# How to use key-paths in NSPredicate on an NSArray of NSStrings?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, key-value-coding

Does anyone know how to use key-paths in NSPredicate?

I'm trying to use key-paths, but an error occurred.
I want to use `"dictate like 'AAA'"` as key-path.

Source code:

```
- (void)Predictate{
    dictate = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"AAA",@"BBB",@"CCC", nil];

    NSPredicate *test = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"dictate like 'AAA'"];

    NSMutableArray *result = [dictate filteredArrayUsingPredicate:test];

    NSLog(@"%@",result);
}
```

This is the error message:

> 2012-01-02 01:33:33.673 filter[1867:707] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:
>   '[<__NSCFConstantString 0x1000022f0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this
>   class is not key value coding-compliant for the key dictate.'

Comment: You get that error because the strings don't have a “`dictate`” property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"self LIKE 'AAA'" works. Tested.

It's kind of subtle fact that you can send `self` to Objective-C object and get the pointer to the object itself (try `[obj performselector:@selector(self)]`). So that's how it works.